# Google Cloud Function - What is the default update behaviour for functions that rely on code in a Repo?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-source-repositories

I have a Google Cloud Function that runs from source code stored in a Google Cloud Source Repository. If I update the source code in the repo, do I have to manually update the cloud function or is this done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic deployment.  You will have to run whatever command line you would normally run to deploy the code to Cloud Functions.